# link list functions in matlab

Tags: c#, arrays, matlab

I'm trying to convert a c# code into a matlab code. So in c# code I have a linklist where x,y coordinates are inserted. I'm using "Array.Resize(ref arr, 1);" to insert x,y value. So whenever I insert values old value goes to the bottom of the array. I'm also using resize method to shrink(or break) the array from certain indexes. How can I recreate this in matlab. I read about reshape method in matlab but I don't understand how to apply it. dlnode method in matlab only can take one value at a time.

```
Point[] arr = new Point[8];
for (int x= 0; x < arr.Length; x++)
{
    Array.Resize<Point>(ref arr, 1);
    arr[x].X = x; (x,y values will get from text boxes) 
    arr[x].Y= y;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do?

```
A = [x y]
B = [A ; B]
```

And by opposite:

```
A = B(:,1)
B = B(:,2:end)
```

Comment: thanks, i think its not the answer i'm looking for, i need to make a list ,and as i enter new values the old value should go to the bottom and i should be able to shrink the original array using a index. like it does in c#

Comment: Give us an example of what you're looking for.  What the array starts with, what it looks like after entering one new value, and what a "shrunk" array looks like.

Comment: Shrink by index: `B = [B(:,1:index-1) ; B(:,index+1:end)]` The part with old values to bottom I don't actually understand. If You put a new pair in (for example) index=5, than You want the old values from index 5 to go to the bottom of the array?

Comment: so if first array will look like this
[(1,1), (2,2)]
and if enter another x,y coordinate ex: (5,5) array will look like this:
[(5,5),(1,1),(2,2)] and when use  Array.Resize<Point>(ref arr, 1) 
array will be [(2,2)] .

Comment: All of this you can do with what I have written before.

Comment: @mikes thanks mike, can you explain how to use for a 2d array , for x and y coordinates thanks again

Comment: But everythign I have written is for a 2D array. 
`B = [ 1 1 ; 2 2 ]`
Add a new value `A = [5 5]`:
`B = [A ; B]`
`B = [ 5 5 ; 1 1 ; 2 2 ]`
Resize to point (2 2):
`B = B(:,end)`
`B = [ 2 2 ]`